# vim plugin for exploring macros written by c/c++

Tags: c++, c, vim, macros

Is there a plugin which can expand c/c++ macros in vim? such as [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/macro-features.html) do?

Comment: I'm not sure if such plugin exists, but probably it does not. So just in case someone who is looking for it is willing to write one, I'll leave here [this link](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/RewriteMacros_8cpp_source.html).

Comment: @xaizek I'll try to study how to write one:)

Answer (score 0):

[Vim C++ macro-like expansion script](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://cs-haven.blogspot.com/2009/04/vim-c-macro-like-expansion-script.html&ei=CsRGUPboA8TQsgbWnoHoBg&usg=AFQjCNEWY7jteQxdo9zMzzAeIMJOyW8pEg&sig2=zirF13ExJHp_4pVqRKmMuQ)

Comment: I found that before asking the question, I'm asking for a script which could expand an exist c/c++ macro.