# VIM plugin for recursively expanding and showing C/C++ macros

Tags: c++, c, vim, macros

The C code that I am working on has lots of macros everywhere. I need to see expanded states of the macros to decrease my coding time.

1) What is the best way of code development considering codes with many macros? For example, there is variable which is probably declared somewhere in the macros and I have to search all macros to find its type.

2) Although using `ctags` in VIM helps me to jump to the macro definition, is there a VIM plugin that recursively expands and shows C/C++ macros in a C/C++ file while I am editing the file?

P.S. There is a similar question here but its answers are not related with the question:
[vim plugin for exploring macros written by c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273993/vim-plugin-for-exploring-macros-written-by-c-c)

P.P.S. When I use the solution at [Seeing expanded C macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985403/seeing-expanded-c-macros), I got a huge file that contains all other include files and so on. Also the whole file cannot be preprocessed because I have to change the `cmake` build system.

Comment: Does this help [GCC dump preprocessor defines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2224334/1606345)?

Comment: The best way to deal with code full of macros is fire.

Comment: @KeineLust, it helps to find out expanded macros, however I have to first find out the header file that contains the macro possibly using `grep`, etc.

Comment: Are you doing obfuscation code in somehow ?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to find/write a libclang module that knows how to expand a macro. From here, you'll have to integrate it in Vim.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, the code is written like the one in http://stackoverflow.com/a/652945/1632456